# Accessing port 80 using hostname.local from outside guest

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, bonjour, avahi

I have a ubuntu server running inside VM. The hostname is ubuntu. I am able to ping "ubuntu.local" from the host and also from other computers in the same network. However, when I try to browse to http://ubuntu.local in a web browser I'm not able to see the website. The webserver is indeed running in the VM. I also installed bonjour and ping to ubuntu.local is working as I mentioned before.

Any ideas of how to make http calls work?

Comment: are you trying to access http://ubuntu.local via a computer connected internally to the same network as the web server or from an outside connection?   If it is outside, .local addresses are not routable on the public internet.   You may want to look into signing up for a dynamic DNS account and then download the client to your webserver and run it.  That will give you a publicly accessible DNS domain (like http://myserver.freedns.com or something similar).  You may also have to allow traffic from port 80 from the internet to access your network from the outside.

Comment: I just re-read your question.   So you are running an Ubuntu VM, what software are you using?  Virtualbox?   Regardless of what you are using, you need to make sure you are using a bridged network adapter for your VM.   If you have not changed the settings for the network adapter, I can pretty well assure you that it is set to NAT, which you will need to change to bridged mode.   What machine are you trying to ping/browse ubuntu.local from?   The host machine running the VM?   if so, that would make sense why you can ping it from the host machine.   Need more information about your setup..

Comment: VirtualBox with bridged adapter. Ping works from host and other computers. Browsing http does not work from anywhere (I can still browse using the guest IP address)